# Eclipse Appengine project: "errors exist in required project" but nothing is red on debug or run

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

My top level project directory keeps having a red icon showing me that there's something wrong.  However, none of my files are marked red, suggesting that I don't have any errors in them.

When I execute either Run or Debug, I receive the notification that "errors exist in required project".  I proceed in spite of this, and my project works as expected.  In my error log, I observe that when the debug/run is starting up, receive this error:
"!ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.core 4 0 2012-10-24 12:59:50.251
!MESSAGE Could not change permissions on the launch config file"

My appengine-web.xml and web.xml files are in the correct locations and appengine-web.xml has the correct reference to logging.properties, but on the console I see that "INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger" is printed out.

My logging.properties file only has this:
.level = WARNING
and I have a log4j.properties file in my WEB-INF/classes directory, which has the standard "Google Plugin for Eclipse"-generated log4j.properties file.

**I would love to understand 2 things:
1) How do I change the JettyLogger to actually not be null, to print to the console.
2) Why does my project keep telling me that errors exist, when I can see no evidence of this in the performance of my project?**

A few more things:  my project is running on JRE6, with Appengine sdk 1.7.2, and the project successfully deploys onto Appspot.

Originally, I had been using JRE7.  When I found out I needed to use JRE6, I uninstalled JRE7, added JRE6 to my build path, **and I cleaned my project**.  I have checked my WEB-INF/classes directory's files' timestamps to make sure that the project is being rebuilt.  I suspect that something relating to this JRE change is the cause, but cleaning the project has not resolved the issue.

This project is under Git source control, using the EGit plugin.

Thank you for your time, patience in reading my verbose post.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the facets of my project were still set to 1.7.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/465060/vc/Eclipse-Dynamic-Web-Project-Java